# LCB Unable to find imported module 'com.livecode.library.scriptitems'

Tags: livecode

I'm working on a LiveCode widget and importing the scriptitems library. When I click "test" in the "Extension Builder" I get the error

`Unable to find imported module 'com.livecode.library.scriptitems'`

Answer (score 1):

So after investigation it turns out that the scriptitems library is only available in LiveCode 9.0. So I just stopped trying to use it and now my widget compiles correctly.